# Nuttx rtos многозадачность

Tags: stm32, микроконтроллеры

Доброго времени суток.

С недавнего времени возникла острая необходимость написания прошивки на основе Nuttx RTOS.
Необходимо реализовать несколько параллельных задач (пусть для начала это будет мигание светодиодов с разной частотой).

Естественно просмотрел всю информацию с официального сайта nuttx: https://nuttx.apache.org/ а также официальный youtube канал https://www.youtube.com/c/NuttXChannel, и другие источники.

На youtube канале рассмотрены простейшие примеры использования nuttx: запуск встроенных примеров и командной строки. Примеров на многозадачность не нашел, как и на просторах интернета.
На официально сайте приведено только описание функций, для работы с многозадачностью. Я использую для своих проектов плату c микроконтроллером stm32f103c8t6 minimum (blue pill).

У  кого есть опыт разработки под nuttx rtos прошу поделиться простым примером, где запускается две и более задачи и если несложно прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, как запускаются задачи на nuttx.
Буду очень признателен.

Comment: А почему не FreeRTOS, для которой в инете море информации?

Comment: Для моей будущей работы требуется именно nuttx

Comment: @ГеннадийП, уж `Zephyr` ныне попопулярнее будет.